# Scala underscores in names

Tags: scala

I've read multiple style guidelines and other resources stating it's a bad idea to use underscores in method/variable/other names.

What are the technical reasons behind this?

I'm very accustomed to e.g. prepending helper functions with _. There are also functions that should be private that I want to make public so I can access them via the REPL. Other naming conventions like using a "helper" suffix just seem cumbersome.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The wildcard operator `_` is used heavily in Scala.  So:

```
xs map (_.x)  // Call the x method of every element
xs map (_x)   // Pass every element through the _x method
```

is confusing.  You have to look very carefully to see if the underscore is prepended.

However, internal underscores are harder to confuse:

```
xs map (my_method)  // No similar form where _ stands for the list element
```

So these are less problematic, but the underscores *still* catch the eye a little when one is looking for closures.  This is probably why they're discouraged, but to be honest, I use them all the time, particularly in things like implicit defs and internal variables where they won't have much or any exposure in an interface.

Comment: this is a very constructed case: you have an `xs: Seq[T: {def x: U}]`. for the error to occur, you need exactly a `_x: {def apply(y: T): U}`. if either of these three constraints isn’t there, it doesn’t compile. it has to be exactly named `_x`, has to be callable with a single `T` argument, which has to return an `U`. i’m not even slightly convinced.

Comment: @flying sheep - It's not likely that you'll have a name collision of that sort; the point is that when you are reading quickly through only-somewhat-familiar code, you don't know immediately whether a private method in local code or a public method on the collection element is in play.  You can, of course, figure out quite quickly, but you can figure it out _even faster_ if you can tell from shape at a distance.

Answer (score 5):

I only know the reason I avoid underscores in names: they are an important part of Scala syntax that show up all over the place. Sure, you *can* put them in names, but it tends to slow down the human parser in my experience.

But I must confess I do occasionally use an underscore prefix for private variables in mutable objects, if I want the non-underscored name for public methods. It would be nice if we could use primes (foo') like Haskell, but I think that would be lexically difficult.

Answer (score 2):

i think those specs just talk about underscores *in* names.

in what (sane) way should you write the following, if not this way?

```
object getterSetter {
    var _variable: Option[Double] = None
    def variable = _variable
    def variable_=(newVal: Double) { _variable = Some(newVal) }
}
```

i think the reason for `camelCase` instead of `embedded_underscores` is simply that java uses that and when working with java libraries, consistency can be only kept like that.

Comment: Prepending with underscores is a _convention_; you still have to declare it private.  Also, you could use `variableHidden` or any number of other things instead of `_variable`.

Comment: oh, you are right. must have confused that. but `variableHidden`? seriously?

Comment: I also use `_variable`, but the argument in Rex Kerr's answer is interesting.

Comment: @Alexey: not exactly. check my comment on it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the `_` being used all over the language not just as a wildcard but also as parts of public APIs like in tuples (`someTuple._1` etc) it is also interpreted specially by the compiler in some cases. For instance in **setters**, which have to be suffixed with `_=` or in **unary operators**, which have to be prefixed with `unary_`.

All this makes it really easy to use a "special name" by accident or misinterpret an "ordinary name" when someone used something similar but not exactly the same as a "special name". It won't matter if it happened by accident or due to lack of knowledge, but when it does you will probably spend a couple of hours looking for a bug. So don't use them unless you really have to. DSLs are as always an exception.