# Scala style guideline for underscore in identifiers

Tags: scala

I have accepted from many other languages that underscores have as much freedom as alphabets in an identifier. Hence `_v` and `v_`. Also that trailing underscores are **recommended** to avoid ambiguity with reserved keywords (`class_`, `case_`).

```
val abc_=0
<console>:1: error: '=' expected but integer literal found.
       val abc_=0
```

Underscores being an important part of Scala typing system, what is the recommended way to **use them in identifiers**, so that parser and human can both be happy? What are all possible ambiguities that identifiers with underscores bring?

Leading whitespaces seem to add to confusion `_class` instead of `class_`.

---

Related questions:

- [What are all the uses of an underscore in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala)
- [Scala underscores in names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277859/scala-underscores-in-names)

Comment: Check out the [style guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html).

Comment: I've never seen the `class_` thing. I usually see creative misspelling (e.g. `clazz`), or, Scala lets you use keywords as identifiers if you surround them with backticks.

Comment: @SethTisue, I got it from Python's PEP8 style guide. My bad; thinking it was a standard.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Trailing underscores are a bad idea because things like `x_+` are valid variable names on their own.  Don't use trailing underscores at all.

Leading underscores are less bad of an idea, but it's still hard to visually parse things like `_myfunc _`.  There is something of a convention to make private members that hold constructor arguments of the same name start with `_`: `class X(x: Int) { private var _x = x }`.  My recommendation is *don't do it*.  You're asking for confusion.  Use `myX` or `theX` or `xLocal` or `xi` or something for your internal variable.  Still, if you *do* go with `_x`, you'll have good company; people will tend to know what you mean.

Underscores within a name are not widely used, since camel case is the standard.  The exception that I make is that I use underscores within implicit defs that are not expected to be used by hand, and instead state why the conversion is taking place: `tuple2_can_expand` might add an `expand` method to convert a `Tuple2` into a `Tuple3`, for example.

Answer (score 6):

There is only one place you *need* underscores in identifiers: between alphanumeric characters and other. In fact, that's just what happens in your case: the parser thinks you are declaring `val abc_=` and don't have `=` after it! Most common use is for "setter" methods:

```
def prop: String // or some other type
def prop_=(v: String)
```

I've also seen `predicate_?` instead of more Java-like `isPredicate`.

`keyword_` aren't often used, but if you do use them, don't skimp on the whitespace. Write, e.g., `val abc_ = 0`. But for that matter, `val abc = 0` is more readable than `val abc=0` as well, so you should have whitespace there anyway. As Rex Kerr says, `_privateVariable` is acceptable, but not recommended practice.

Comment: Do you know why "predicate_?" and not "predicate?".  Just curious.

Comment: @EdStaub Primarily so you can still write things like `x+y` or `x=y` and not have the parser think that's a single identifier, I think.